# Active Admin Edit Admin User Failing (ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `find_by_id' for Admin:Module))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have setup active admin and everything is working well except for the ability for admin users edit any information (mainly want to be able to edit password). I also want to be able to limit which user each admin can edit.

When I click on edit admin user I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `find_by_id' for Admin:Module))
1: insert_tag renderer_for(:edit)
activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/view_helpers/breadcrumb_helper.rb:15:in `block in     breadcrumb_links'
activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/view_helpers/breadcrumb_helper.rb:10:in `each'
activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/view_helpers/breadcrumb_helper.rb:10:in `each_with_index'
activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/view_helpers/breadcrumb_helper.rb:10:in `each'
activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/view_helpers/breadcrumb_helper.rb:10:in `map'
activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/view_helpers/breadcrumb_helper.rb:10:in `breadcrumb_links'
arbre (1.0.2) lib/arbre/element.rb:180:in `method_missing'
```

Here is my Admin Controller

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser, :as => 'Admin' do   
  actions :all

  index do                            
    column :email                     
    column :current_sign_in_at        
    column :last_sign_in_at           
    column :sign_in_count             
    default_actions                   
 end                                 

  filter :email                       

   form do |f|       
     f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys                  
     f.inputs "Admin Details" do       
       f.input :email                  
       f.input :password               
       f.input :password_confirmation  
    end                               
     f.actions                         
   end                                 
 end
```

Comment: did you permit all admin's attributes (which you want to edit) and  actions (particularly :edit)?

Comment: yes, i get the error when i try to access the edit page (admin/admins/1/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following line under `actions :all`

```
 permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

If that won't help, try to debug:

- check, if all AdminUsers have ad `id`;
- also I would remove `as: 'Admin'` to check, if that could cause the error;

I would also write filter as follows:

```
filter :email, as: :select, collection: -> { AdminUser.pluck(:email)}
```